# Not able to drop a draggable on dynamically created droppable inside another droppable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

Please see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/9bfjy8mh/).

I want to add a new `div` (`Row in my example`) that can be added to it another `div` (`Button in my example`) by drag and drop (**jQuery UI**).

I created new div (`$row`) in helper function (`addNewRow`) and added new function for drag and drop another div to it like this:

```
$('.rowDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewRow,       
        revert: "invalid",
    });

// helper function
function addNewRow() {
     $row = $(document.createElement('div'));
     $row.attr("id","droppableDiv");
     $row.html("drop here");
     $row.droppable({
        accept: ".buttonDashboard",
       // greedy: true,
        drop: function (ev, ui) {
        alert('ok');                    
        },
    });
     return $row;
}
```

I expected that `ok` message would appear by dropping `div` with `buttonDashboard` class to `div` with `rowDraggable` but `drop` function doesn't fire.

Is it correct to add `drop` function in helper function?

If it is incorrect, then what is the solution to that?

Thanks advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your jsfiddle and [**created a new DEMO which works**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/9bfjy8mh/2/)

I have removed the `droppable` initialization code from the `helper` function restructured your code.

Here is the modified code:

```
var rowIndex = 0;
var buttonIndex = 0;

$(init);

function init() {
    $('.rowDashboard').draggable({
        containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewRow,       
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $('#content').droppable({
                    greedy: true,
            accept: ".rowDashboard",
            drop: function (ev, ui) {
                ui.helper.attr('style', '');
                $(ui.helper).addClass('rowDraggable');
                $item = $(ui.helper).clone();
                $item.appendTo('#content');
                //console.log('dropped');
                $item.droppable({
                    accept: ".buttonDashboard",
                    greedy: true,
                    drop: function (ev, ui) {
                    alert('ok');                    
                    },
                });
            },
        });       

    //------- buttonDraggable -----------
    $('.buttonDashboard').draggable({
        //containment: '#content',
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: addNewButton,
        //helper: "clone"
    });      
}

function addNewButton() {
    buttonIndex++;
    return '<input type=\'button\' value=\'button ' + buttonIndex + ' \'>   </input>';
}

function addNewRow() {
     $row = $(document.createElement('div'));
     //$row.attr("id","droppableDiv");
     $row.html("drop here");

     return $row;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. When I asked this question I was new to jQuery-UI and after one week I tackled this problem like your code but I forgot to add answer. Anyway your answer is correct and I accept it.